# Run tasks before build in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, cmd, msbuild, nuget, pre-build-event

I use Selenium with Chrome to do Web UI automation test.

chromedriver.exe is got from nuget repository. Need to replace with a local chromedriver.exe file sometimes for the version is unmatched with Chrome and I do this in [NUnit.Framework.SetUp].

Rebuild would restore chromedriver.exe from nuget repository. And, sometimes it would failed for chromedriver.exe is running (debug not ended properly last time).
I try to kill chromedriver.exe before build by added

```
taskkill /im chromedriver.exe /f 2>nul
```

in pre-build event in visual studio. Seems like restore chromedriver.exe from nuget repository runs before pre-build event and I got below error:

17>  Deleting file "C:\code\50\bin\Debug\chromedriver.exe".
17>C:\code\50\packages\Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver.99.0.4844.5100\build\Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver.targets(92,5): error MSB3061: Unable to delete file "C:\code\50\bin\Debug\chromedriver.exe". Access to the path 'C:\code\50\bin\Debug\chromedriver.exe' is denied.

Anyone knows that how to kill chromedriver.exe process before build and before nuget package restore?

Comment: Is it possible to add target in Directory.Build.targets? How?

Answer (score 0):

Directory.Build.targets works

```
<Project>
  <Target Name="DriverCleanUp" BeforeTargets="CoreClean">
    <Exec Command="taskkill /im chromedriver.exe /f 2>nul" IgnoreExitCode="true"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```